# XSLT Nested Templating

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I am trying to build a tree like structure for Country/Province/City but for some reason my templates are rendering wrong

XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hierarchy.xsl" ?>
<data>

<place id="CA" name="Canada"/>

<place parent="CA" id="ON" name="Ontario"/>
<place parent="CA" id="QC" name="Quebec"/>
<place parent="CA" id="NS" name="Nova Scotia"/>
<place parent="CA" id="NB" name="New Brunswick"/>
<place parent="CA" id="MB" name="Manitoba"/>
<place parent="CA" id="BC" name="British Columbia"/>
<place parent="CA" id="PE" name="Prince Edward Island"/>
<place parent="CA" id="SK" name="Saskatchewan"/>
<place parent="CA" id="AB" name="Alberta"/>
<place parent="CA" id="NL" name="Newfoundland and Labrador"/>

<place parent="ON" name="Barrie"/>
<place parent="ON" name="Belleville"/>
<place parent="ON" name="Brampton"/>
<place parent="ON" name="Brant"/>
<place parent="ON" name="Brantford"/>
<place parent="ON" name="Brockville"/>
<place parent="QC" name="Acton Vale"/>
<place parent="QC" name="Alma"/>
<place parent="QC" name="Amos"/>
<place parent="QC" name="Amqui"/>
<place parent="QC" name="Asbestos"/>
<place parent="MB" name="Brandon"/>
<place parent="MB" name="Dauphin"/>
<place parent="MB" name="Flin Flon"/>
<place parent="MB" name="Morden"/>
<place parent="MB" name="Portage la Prairie"/>
<place parent="PE" name="Charlottetown"/>
<place parent="PE" name="Summerside"/>
<place parent="PE" name="Alberton"/>
<place parent="PE" name="Borden-Carleton"/>
<place parent="PE" name="Cornwall"/>
<place parent="PE" name="Georgetown"/>
<place parent="PE" name="Kensington"/>
<place parent="PE" name="Montague"/>

<place parent="FR" id="LL" name="Newfoundland and Labrador"/>
<place id="FR" name="France"/>
<place id="JP" name="Japan"/>

</data>
```

My XSLT is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//place"/>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="place[not(@parent)]">
<li> <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></li>
<xsl:apply-templates select="place[@parent='CA']"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="place[@parent='CA']">
<ul>
  <li> <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></li>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="place[@parent='ON']"/>
</ul>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="place[@parent='ON']">
<li> <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output I am getting is

Canada
  Provinces
cities

Now the problem is my cities for Ontario are rendering after all of the provinces are rendered. I need help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell what you want exactly because you don't show your desired result, but I'll try anyway.

I'd suggest using an `xsl:key` to reference `place`'s by the `parent` attribute.

Then you can apply-templates using the current `id` attribute.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<data>

    <place id="CA" name="Canada"/>

    <place parent="CA" id="ON" name="Ontario"/>
    <place parent="CA" id="QC" name="Quebec"/>
    <place parent="CA" id="NS" name="Nova Scotia"/>
    <place parent="CA" id="NB" name="New Brunswick"/>
    <place parent="CA" id="MB" name="Manitoba"/>
    <place parent="CA" id="BC" name="British Columbia"/>
    <place parent="CA" id="PE" name="Prince Edward Island"/>
    <place parent="CA" id="SK" name="Saskatchewan"/>
    <place parent="CA" id="AB" name="Alberta"/>
    <place parent="CA" id="NL" name="Newfoundland and Labrador"/>

    <place parent="ON" name="Barrie"/>
    <place parent="ON" name="Belleville"/>
    <place parent="ON" name="Brampton"/>
    <place parent="ON" name="Brant"/>
    <place parent="ON" name="Brantford"/>
    <place parent="ON" name="Brockville"/>
    <place parent="QC" name="Acton Vale"/>
    <place parent="QC" name="Alma"/>
    <place parent="QC" name="Amos"/>
    <place parent="QC" name="Amqui"/>
    <place parent="QC" name="Asbestos"/>
    <place parent="MB" name="Brandon"/>
    <place parent="MB" name="Dauphin"/>
    <place parent="MB" name="Flin Flon"/>
    <place parent="MB" name="Morden"/>
    <place parent="MB" name="Portage la Prairie"/>
    <place parent="PE" name="Charlottetown"/>
    <place parent="PE" name="Summerside"/>
    <place parent="PE" name="Alberton"/>
    <place parent="PE" name="Borden-Carleton"/>
    <place parent="PE" name="Cornwall"/>
    <place parent="PE" name="Georgetown"/>
    <place parent="PE" name="Kensington"/>
    <place parent="PE" name="Montague"/>

    <place parent="FR" id="LL" name="Newfoundland and Labrador"/>
    <place id="FR" name="France"/>
    <place id="JP" name="Japan"/>

</data>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--This key matches "place" elements that have a "parent" attribute.
  The "parent" attribute is used as the value of the key.
  For example, <place parent="CA" id="ON" name="Ontario"/> would
  have the key "CA" (along with "Quebec", "Nova Scotia", etc.).-->
  <xsl:key name="places" match="place[@parent]" use="@parent"/>

  <!--This template matches the root element "data".-->
  <xsl:template match="/data">
    <html>
      <body>
        <ul>
          <!--We apply-templates only to "place" elements that do not
          have a "parent" attribute (ie "Canada", "France", and 
          "Japan"). These elements will be processed in document
          order. Since "Canada" appears first in the document, it
          will be processed first.-->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="place[not(@parent)]"/>
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--This template matches any "place" element.-->
  <xsl:template match="place">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      <!--This xsl:if is used to check to see if there 
      are any "place" elements with the key of the "id" attribute.
      For example, if the current "place" element was 
      <place id="CA" name="Canada"/> the test would resolve to 
      "key('places','CA')". If there are "place" elements with
      that key, we output a new "ul" and apply-templates to those
      elements.-->
      <xsl:if test="key('places',@id)">
        <ul>
          <!--Here is where we apply-templates (process) to elements 
          using the "id" attribute of the current "place" element.
          For example, if the current "id" attribute was "CA", we'd
          be processing any "place" elements with the "parent" attribute
          value "CA" (which is what the key was created with ("use" 
          attribute of "xsl:key" above)). This all happens in document
          order.-->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('places',@id)"/>        
        </ul>        
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML Output**

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>Canada
            <ul>
               <li>Ontario
                  <ul>
                     <li>Barrie</li>
                     <li>Belleville</li>
                     <li>Brampton</li>
                     <li>Brant</li>
                     <li>Brantford</li>
                     <li>Brockville</li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>Quebec
                  <ul>
                     <li>Acton Vale</li>
                     <li>Alma</li>
                     <li>Amos</li>
                     <li>Amqui</li>
                     <li>Asbestos</li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>Nova Scotia</li>
               <li>New Brunswick</li>
               <li>Manitoba
                  <ul>
                     <li>Brandon</li>
                     <li>Dauphin</li>
                     <li>Flin Flon</li>
                     <li>Morden</li>
                     <li>Portage la Prairie</li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>British Columbia</li>
               <li>Prince Edward Island
                  <ul>
                     <li>Charlottetown</li>
                     <li>Summerside</li>
                     <li>Alberton</li>
                     <li>Borden-Carleton</li>
                     <li>Cornwall</li>
                     <li>Georgetown</li>
                     <li>Kensington</li>
                     <li>Montague</li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>Saskatchewan</li>
               <li>Alberta</li>
               <li>Newfoundland and Labrador</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>France
            <ul>
               <li>Newfoundland and Labrador</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>Japan</li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here's a simplified version of how the stylesheet would process a smaller set of data (ignoring
result tree fragments, serialization, etc.):

```
<data>
    <place id="CA" name="Canada"/>
    <place parent="CA" id="ON" name="Ontario"/>
    <place parent="ON" name="Barrie"/>
    <place parent="FR" id="LL" name="Newfoundland and Labrador"/>
    <place id="FR" name="France"/>
</data>
```

1. `<data>` gets matched by the first template (`match="/data"`).
2. The "html", "body", and first "ul" elements are output.
3. Inside the "ul" we process (select) only the `<place>` elements that do not have a `parent` attribute (Canada and France).
4. `<place id="CA" name="Canada"/>` gets matched by the second template (`match="place"`).
5. An "li" element is output with the `name` attribute value ("Canada").
6. Inside the "li", we check to see if the key "places" contains any nodes with the key "CA" (based on the `id` attribute value of the current `place` element).
7. There is a node with the key "CA" (`<place parent="CA" id="ON" name="Ontario"/>`) so it outputs a new "ul" element.
8. Inside that UL we process the nodes with that key.
9. `<place parent="CA" id="ON" name="Ontario"/>` gets matched by the second template (`match="place"`).
10. An "li" element is output with the `name` attribute value ("Ontario").
11. Inside the "li", we check to see if the key "places" contains any nodes with the key "ON" (based on the `id` attribute value of the current `place` element).
12. There is a node with the key "ON" (`<place parent="ON" name="Barrie"/>`) so it outputs a new "ul" element.
13. Inside that UL we process the nodes with that key.
14. `<place parent="ON" name="Barrie"/>` gets matched by the second template (`match="place"`).
15. An "li" element is output with the `name` attribute value ("Barrie").
16. Inside the "li", the key test fails because the current `place` element does not have an `id` element.
17. The processing for `<place id="CA" name="Canada"/>` is done.
18. The next `place` element that does not have a `parent` attribute gets processed. (Basically it's going back to step 3 to resume processing.)
19. `<place id="FR" name="France"/>` gets matched by the second template (`match="place"`).
20. An "li" element is output with the `name` attribute value ("France").
21. Inside the "li", we check to see if the key "places" contains any nodes with the key "FR" (based on the `id` attribute value of the current `place` element).
22. There is a node with the key "FR" (`<place parent="FR" id="LL" name="Newfoundland and Labrador"/>`) so it outputs a new "ul" element.
23. Inside that UL we process the nodes with that key.
24. `<place parent="FR" id="LL" name="Newfoundland and Labrador"/>` gets matched by the second template (`match="place"`).
25. An "li" element is output with the `name` attribute value ("Newfoundland and Labrador").
26. Inside the "li", we check to see if the key "places" contains any nodes with the key "LL" (based on the `id` attribute value of the current `place` element).
27. There are no nodes with the key "LL" so the processing for `<place parent="FR" id="LL" name="Newfoundland and Labrador"/>` is done.
28. There are no more `place` elements that didn't have `parent` attributes to process so all processing is done.

Hopefully I didn't miss any steps.

Also see the spec section ["5. Template Rules"](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#rules) for more information (especially 5.1 and 5.8).

Comment: Hey Daniel. Your solution gives the correct output. But I am rather confused in regards to the order of the traversal. Can you please guide me in regards to how the code actually determines where to insert the elements in the correct order. 

For example does it print all the provinces first and then add the cities to it, or whether it prints one province and then prints all its cities. I just want to understand the flow of code Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at why your code is wrong.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
...
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//place"/>
...
</html>
```

Here you're processing all places, regardless of their depth in the logical hierarchy.

```
<xsl:template match="place[not(@parent)]">
  <li> <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></li>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="place[@parent='CA']"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here it looks as if you're trying to process top-level places by outputting the name of the place and then processing its children. But none of the places in your input have any (XML) children, they are all empty elements. So the `xsl:apply-templates` here will do nothing. And if it did do something, it would do the wrong thing, because you would then be processing the non-top-level places twice, once from the root template and once from their parent.

I think that what you want to do here is a recursive descent over the logical (geographical) hierarchy, which is different from the XML tree hierarchy. The way to do that is that whenever you process a node in the hierarchy, it should output its own details, and then apply-templates to process its logical children:

```
<xsl:template match="place">
  <li>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></p>
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="(logical children)"/>
    </ul>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```

One way to select the "logical children" is `select="//place[@parent=current()/@id]"`

But unless you're using an XSLT processor (such as Saxon-EE) with a really good optimizer, you'll get better performance by defining a key:

```
<xsl:key name="k" match="place" use="@id"/>
```

then

```
select="key('k', @parent)"
```

Comment: I think you have the key backwards. If you use `@id` for the xsl:key and then select using `@parent`, you'll end up with things like "Ontario" -> "Canada" instead of "Canada" -> "Ontario". (That's if you got anything other than just the top level places since the first apply-templates should be selecting `places[not(@parent)]`.)